# Div с postion:absolute имеет отступ сверху

Tags: html, css

`div` с `position:absolute` (у родителя `position:relative`), с `top:0`, с `left:0` имеет отступ сверху (не считая стандартный `margin` у `body`).

Но если убрать параграф, то `div` будет без этого отступа.

Почему так?

---

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
<div>div div</div>
```

Comment: Для тега `body` стиль `position: relative` обязателен?

Comment: Необходимо обнулить - *{margin: 0;}

Comment: Вот так будет https://jsfiddle.net/9vaoy63g/ без `position: relative` для `body`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что по умолчанию не только у `<body>` есть отступы, но и `<p>`, например — который и отодвигает `<body>` вниз, а значит и абсолютно позиционированный див за ними следом.

Comment: В смысле? Как параграф может отодвигать body вниз?

Comment: Верхний марджин первого вложенного блока распространяется за пределы родительского блока — вот так и может. Структура страницы такова html > body > p, у body по умолчанию есть марджины 8 пкс, они отодвигают body от html, у параграфа 1.5em — когда он первый, body начинает отодвигаться не на 8 пкс, а на 1.5em.

Answer (score 0):

Обнулите margin и padding

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: А если мне нужно оставить отступы у параграфа? Так результат будет тот же самый.

Comment: у body надо убрать position:relative;

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто нужно обнулить `margin` и `padding`:

```
.class{ 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0
}
```

**UPD** - это возникает из-за того, что у некоторых элементов есть свой "дефолтный" `padding` или `margin`. В таких случаях его обычно обнуляют, а это выше :)

Comment: А если мне нужно оставить отступы у параграфа? Так результат будет тот же самый.

Comment: Тогда добавьте параграфу `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Мне нужен отступ сверху.