# Div с 'postion:absolute' имеет отступ сверху

Tags: html, css, position

`div` с `position:absolute` (у родителя `position:relative`), с `top:0`, с `left:0` имеет отступ сверху (не считая стандартный `margin` у `body`).

Но если убрать параграф, то `div` будет без этого отступа.

- Обнулить 'margin' немогу, так-как нужен 'margin-top' у 'p'.
- 'position:relative' у 'body' обязателен, так как хочу, чтобы 'top' и 'left' отсчитывались от края родительского элемента ('body').

Почему так?

P.S уже задавал такой вопрос но на него нет нормального ответа - [Div с postion:absolute имеет отступ сверху](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853156/div-%D1%81-postionabsolute-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83)

---

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
<div>div div</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Div с postion:absolute имеет отступ сверху](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853156/div-%d1%81-postionabsolute-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85%d1%83)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос наверняка пойдёт как дубль, но всё-же отвечу. Данное явление называется выпадание отступа, происходит в том случае, когда у родительского блока отсутствует контент до выпадающего блока и не задана граница и внутренний отступ. Исходя из вышесказанного, избавиться от проблемы можно заданием padding или border. Вот тут я задал для body padding-top: 1px;

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
<div>div div</div>
```